# MySQL Database field update should trigger function in ios

Tags: ios, mysql, node.js, swift3

I want to sent data to client which is IOS, when database field is updated, do I have to do back end api call every seconds to check whether data is updated ? or is their any alternative way to make this happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do that you are going to drain the user's battery.
You should use a cloud messaging solution like Firebase, Onesignal, or Urbanarship to notify the devices when there is an update they should be aware of.

The idea is when the program in the server updates the database, it also sends the corresponding data message to the devices for them to update calling the api.

For not all of the devices calling your api at the same time, include some randomness in the timing of the update call to the server.

Comment: So what If I do not have option to use firebase ? what can I do if not doing the back end api call every 10 seconds ?

Comment: can RxSwift solve my problem ? Sorry if this is very basic question, the idea is when USER A request to USER B and if USER B Accepts the request, I want to show USER A that your request has been accepted and also show USER B that USER A has requested something... Let me know what do you think ?

Comment: Your use case is what Cloud Messaging solves. If you can't use that, I'd call the api when the user interacts with the app (clicking a button, or changing to a differetn screen). But polling every 1, 5, 10 seconds is not the way to go.

Comment: ohh okay, so that is the push notification right ? User will be getting push notification right ? What if user A has the app open and want to show the pop up instead of push notification ? in that case also the cloud messaging will solve my problem ?

Comment: You can send a message with payload of data and handle the data in app.